# Adding feature to remote geodatabase takes a long time

Tags: arcobjects, spatial-database

I have a program that I must add some features to a `feature class` that is in a sql server remote database. But when I want to open connection and add them, it takes a long time, about one or two minutes and it is not good. I tried to add them manually using SQL statements and I cannot do that if I enable geodatabase on my database. So if I want to add features manually, I should not enable geodatabase. On the other hand, I want to edit shapes using arcobject so I must enable geodatabase.

Here is the question:

- If I dont enable geodatabase, I can load and add features very fast and it is great but I cannot edit them using arcobject.
- If I enable geodatabase I can edit features but it is too slow.

What are your suggestions? Is there an alternative way? Are there any libraries that I can use to edit shapes directly from none geodatabase?